# Flutter Range Error: Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I got an error when i tried to get data from a drop down. I want to take the drop down selected value to get data using 'getclientAmc' method

When i print 'selectedType' it show the value on console but i couldn't get data using 'selectedType' variable.

This is my code. I removed imports, styles and some widgets those are not necessary for the dropdown

```
import 'package:amc_new/model/amc_master.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/model/client_amc.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/model/user.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/service/amc_client_service.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/service/amc_master_service.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/service/services.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/service/username_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:amc_new/widgets/loading_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class MyAmc extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAmcState createState() => _MyAmcState();
}

class _MyAmcState extends State<MyAmc> {
  bool circular = false;
  bool isLoading = true;
  AmcMasterService amcMasterService = new AmcMasterService(dioInstance);
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  String selectedType;
  String holder;
  List<String> _amcNo = <String>[];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      circular = true;
    });
    this.fetchUserName();
    this.getAmcNo();
    this.getDropDownItem();
    this.fetchClientAmc();
  }

  AmcMaster amcMaster;
  getAmcNo() async {
    userId = await storage.read(key: "userId");
    print(userId.toString() + "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    var amcMaster = await amcMasterService.getAllAmcNo(userId);
    print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    print(amcMaster);
    if (amcMaster != null) {
      setState(() {
        _amcNo = amcMaster;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  ClientAmcService clientAmcService = new ClientAmcService();

  ClientAmc amcClient;
  fetchClientAmc() async {
    amcClient = await clientAmcService.getclientAmc(selectedType.toString());
    if (amcClient != null) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  getDropDownItem() {
    setState(() {
      holder = selectedType;
    });
    print("holder");
    print(holder);
    return holder;
  }

  UserNameService unameService = new UserNameService();

  User username;
  var userId;
  fetchUserName() async {
    userId = await storage.read(key: "userId");
    username = await unameService.getUsername(userId);
    if (username != null) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (isLoading) {
      return LoadingScreen();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          "Epic Lanka",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
              fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay'),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/dashboard');
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/dashboard');
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/notifications');
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: const Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
            end: const Alignment(0.6, 2.0),
            colors: <Color>[
              const Color(0x1E90FF),
              const Color(0xFFffffff),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.03,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Text(
                username == null ? "(Empty)" : username.uname,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
              ),
            ),
            DropdownButton<String>(
              items: _amcNo
                  .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        child:
                            Text(value, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                        value: value,
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (selectedAMCno) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedType = selectedAMCno;
                  return selectedType;
                });
                print("selectedType");
                print(selectedType);
              },
              value: selectedType,
              isExpanded: false,
              hint: Text(
                "Choose Your AMC No",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.02,
            ),
            Container(
              // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "AMC Serial No",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "AMC No",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Maintanance Start Date",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Maintanance End Date",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Frequency",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Category Name",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "AMC Product No",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width * 0.4,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null ? "(Empty)" : amcClient.amcSerialNo,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null ? "(Empty)" : amcClient.amcNo,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null
                              ? "(Empty)"
                              : amcClient.mtcStartDate.toString(),
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null
                              ? "(Empty)"
                              : amcClient.mtcEndDate.toString(),
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null
                              ? "(Empty)"
                              : amcClient.frequency.toString(),
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null
                              ? "(Empty)"
                              : amcClient.categoryName,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          amcClient == null
                              ? "(Empty)"
                              : amcClient.amcProductNo.toString(),
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height * 0.005,
                        ),
                        // Text(
                        //   "151000",
                        //   style: TextStyle(
                        //       fontSize: 25.0,
                        //       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        //       fontFamily: 'Lateef'),
                        // ),
                        // SizedBox(
                        //   height: size.height * 0.02,
                        // )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The error you posted means that you are trying to access the first index (index 0) of an empty list ("valid value range is empty"). I'm guessing this happens when `_amcNo` has no value yet but the widget is already being built. The code you posted has syntax errors, please post a new snippet, so people can help check it.

Comment: Ok Dear. now i put my full screen code

Comment: Actually '_amcNo' has data dear. It print on the console also

Answer (score 1):

Your 'initState' functions are async..and initState is called when widget is inserted into tree.. so while inserting 'selectedType' is null...

You might want to check for 'null' on selectedType before the getclientAmc call or check for it inside service.. ..or initialize it to something appropriate..